# Reused getter across multiple messages proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have 2 message types in proto

```
message CarrierUPSSettings {
  string default_shipment_weight = 1;
}
```

and

```
message CarrierDHLSettings {
      string default_weight = 1;
    }
```

I would like to have a one name for this field that would be injected into those 2 settings let's call it `default_shipment_weight` and have a logic for getting the value out of it for both instead of simple generated `pb.go`

```
func (m *CarrierUPSSettings) GetDefaultShipmentWeight() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.DefaultShipmentWeight
    }
    return ""
}
```

something like this:

```
 func (m *CarrierUPSSettings) GetDefaultShipmentWeight(conf Configuration, req Request) string {
    if conf.Description != "" {
        return conf.Description
    }
    if req.Descritpion != "" {
        return req.Description
    }
    if m != nil {
        return m.DefaultShipmentWeight
    }
    return ""
}
```

This way I would be able to have the same behavior and reinforce the naming for both carriers since right now there is no naming convention and there is a lot of repeated code across multiple carriers.

How can I achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to generate the method (short of writing a protoc plugin), but you can simply define the GetDefaultShipmentWeight method for the DHL type in a handwritten file next to the generated one.